# oracle weakly typed record as parameter

Tags: oracle, parameters, record

Let's say I have this construct in a PLSQL procedure:

```
...
for rec in
  (
  select a, b, c from t;
  )
loop
  process_record(rec);
end loop;
...

procedure process_record(p_rec in ???)
...
```

How do I pass rec, which is a record of a weakly typed cursor, to a procedure for processing.
I don't want to define a cursor and a type for the record of this type.
Is this possible?

TIA
Gold

Answer (score 0):

you have to define a cursor, or a type (both not needed) in order to tell oracle the structure of the input (unless you want to go down the route or defining an AnyData/AnyType approach.

eg

```
declare
  cursor my_template
  is
    select a,b,c from t;


  procedure process_record(p_rec in my_template%rowtype)
      is
  begin
   null;
  end;
begin
for rec in
  (
  select a, b, c from t
  )
loop
  process_record(rec);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: yes this is the regular way of passing TYPED record. I specifically asked for a way to avoid typed records. thanks anyway.

Comment: right which is why i said the only way is ANYDATA/ANYTYPE. but its a lot of code for this. cant you just have the procedure accept a sys_refcursor instead?

Comment: No. There is a central procedure that reads records using the for..in () loop. At the moment all record processing is done in the loop body. The body became very big and I want to split it to several procedures - refactor it. Inside the loop the record is looks like an untyped record. I hoped this record could be passed to a procedure for processing instead of using it inside the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a simple way to to that (and would be most surprised to see one) but I have a workaround:

Use XMLType as your type:

```
declare

begin
  for rec in (select xmlelement("p_rec", xmlforest(a, b, c)) r from t) loop
    process_record(rec.r);
  end loop;
end;
```

...

```
create or replace procedure process_record(p_rec in XMLtype) as

BEGIN
dbms_output.put(p_rec.extract('//A/text()').getstringval() || ',');
dbms_output.put(p_rec.extract('//B/text()').getstringval() || ',');
dbms_output.put_line(p_rec.extract('//C/text()').getstringval());
END;
```

BTW, why do you want to do that?

Comment: Interesting, but I hoped for an approach that would enable me to use rec.a directly on the process_record procedure... It's a bit complicated and I guess slow on execution. Non the less it's a valid answer (I didn't try this my self). Thank you very much.